# What the heck is IE new Date(string) doing?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datetime

Ok so QA gave me this bug where if a date had a single character starting the month, day or year part of the date (formatted MM/dd/yyyy), that (ONLY in IE) it would parse the date but change it.. So digging around and sure enough its being VERY weird..

This is some sample code of what I am talking about in IE

```
$("#dates").append("<li>04/30/2012 = " + new Date("04/30/2012").toString()+"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>a04/30/2012 = " + new Date("a04/30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>b04/30/2012 = " + new Date("b04/30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>c04/30/2012 = " + new Date("c04/30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>d04/30/2012 = " + new Date("d04/30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>e04/30/2012 = " + new Date("e04/30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/a30/2012 = " + new Date("04/a30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/b30/2012 = " + new Date("04/b30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/c30/2012 = " + new Date("04/c30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/d30/2012 = " + new Date("04/d30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/e30/2012 = " + new Date("04/e30/2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/30/a2012 = " + new Date("04/30/a2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/30/b2012 = " + new Date("04/30/b2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/30/c2012 = " + new Date("04/30/c2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/30/d2012 = " + new Date("04/30/d2012").toString() +"</li>");
$("#dates").append("<li>04/30/e2012 = " + new Date("04/30/e2012").toString() +"</li>");
```

And here is what IE outputs

```
•04/30/2012 = Mon Apr 30 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•a04/30/2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 20:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•b04/30/2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•c04/30/2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 22:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•d04/30/2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•e04/30/2012 = Mon Apr 30 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/a30/2012 = Fri Apr 29 -2012 20:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/b30/2012 = Fri Apr 29 -2012 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/c30/2012 = Fri Apr 29 -2012 22:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/d30/2012 = Fri Apr 29 -2012 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/e30/2012 = Sat Apr 30 -2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/30/a2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 20:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/30/b2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/30/c2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 22:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/30/d2012 = Sun Apr 29 2012 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•04/30/e2012 = Mon Apr 30 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

There is some weird hour add thing going on, except if you add a character to the day part of the format, then it flips the year to BC (from 2012 to -2012???)

We use date pickers so the chance of this happening is pretty limited (but you know QA guys right ;-)... )   So how have others handled this kind of very odd behavior?  (FYI: I checked out moment, but it takes a MM/dd/yyyy date and just passes it down to the browsers date parser, so no dice there.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to check out  (in IE)

http://jsfiddle.net/r7gveLjo/

Comment: Why not use a regex and bounce it back to the user as invalid, rather than trying to parse a clearly invalid date?

Comment: ya that is one answer.... But part of me really wants to know what IE is "trying" to do here... because there is no spec for dates I can find to explain this.

oh and the same date processes handle the JSON dates coming back from the server, so its not as straight forward as just handling a handful of edge cases..

Comment: There _is_ a spec for dates, but at this point it looks like it's completely down to the browser as to what happens with that input, don't rely on it being "correct" in any browser.  [From the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2): _"If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats."_.

Comment: IE must be interpreting it in some way internally that it thinks is ok, otherwise it would use the next sentence: _"Unrecognisable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN"_

Comment: Microsoft are big boy's you would think their documentation would explain behavior like this...  I've read those sentences and unless you are a very interesting individual putting a character in front of a number to add hours to the UTC version of a date (or change the sign of the date's year) would be a bit out of left field vs. "implementation-specific heuristics"

Comment: FWIW, I [found this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx#OtherDateFormats) describing what IE _should_ be doing, but it still doesn't explain this behaviour...

Comment: Is this happening in the BC version of IE? `:)`

Comment: *a* seems to be equal to -4. You should check whether *g* equals +2 to rule out hex values.

Comment: This is one of many reasons we use moment.js for all of our javascript dates.

Comment: @user4749485 You've hit the nail on the head.  From that link: _"The letter "J" is not used"_.  If you put `j` in one of the values in the fiddle, you get `Invalid Date`.  You should write it up as an answer.

Comment: http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--VMdaBkt---/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/18calq4ybym0sjpg.jpg

Comment: @Marko  actually Moment.js does the same thing currently... It falls back to new Date() in cases like this.. (though it does say the behavior is deprecated... It still does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like maybe it's being interpreted as military timezone semantics A-Z.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5.2
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones